# ogr2ogr - Clipping postgis and creating geojson

Tags: postgis, geojson, sql, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to create a geojson file data based on data from my local postgis database using `ogr2ogr`. I'm trying to clip to a specific area and when I start to run the command, everything starts fine, but I then get an `ERROR 6: GeoJSON driver doesn't support creating more than one layer` and I'm not quite sure how to solve it.

Do I need to select only one column in the `SELECT` statement?

Command:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON ./test-buildings.geojson PG:"host=localhost dbname=gis user=*USERNAME* port=5432" -clipdst -84.419932, 33.992761, -84.371342, 34.018029 -clipdstsql 'SELECT way, "building" as type FROM planet_osm_polygon ORDER BY ST_YMin(ST_Envelope(way)) DESC' -progress
```

Comment: What do you get with ogrinfo -al -so when using the same SQL?

Comment: When I run `ogrinfo -al -so 'SELECT way, "building" as type FROM planet_osm_polygon ORDER BY ST_YMin(ST_Envelope(way)) DESC'`, I get a failure to open datasource. Is that syntax right?

Comment: You must include also the data source part PG:...

Comment: Whoops. Totally spaced on that. After running it again with a datasource, [I got this.](https://gist.github.com/briandaviddavidson/1017c98fe69cc2dcba3597159b833e09)

Comment: Looks Ok. Does test-buildings.geojson already exist? It shouldn't.

Comment: Nope. It doesn't exist.

Comment: All right. Clipdstsql is for selecting the geometry that you want to use for clipping from database with SQL. You give it directly as coordinates so clipdstsql is unnecessary, And you are missing -sql parameter which is for selecting the features from database, Without -sql you command is trying to write data from all tables that you have in PostGIS into the same geojson file. Error message makes sense. But your command will not find anything because input data in in a (long time ago deprecated) EPSG:3785 but you give clipping geometry in EPSG:4326. From the manual `(expressed in source SRS)`

Comment: So how would I correctly write this command to get the buildings from `postgis` to `geojson` in that bound box area?

Comment: Give the area in EPSG:3785 coordinates. Remove -clipdstsql and use -sql instead. Or give clipping area as -spat and tell with -spat_srs epsg:4326 that selection is done by long-lat coordinates. Be aware that -spat does not clip, it selects without clipping.

Comment: @user30184 I tried adding a spatial reference, but I didn't have any luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Write the whole ogr2ogr command without PG username/password.

Comment: So that started running and output a geojson file fine, but I need to clip it to a specific area. Can I use `clipsrc` or do I use `spat` with some other flag?

Comment: Tell us what you want to do. Your data in the database is in EPSG:3785. Do you want to clip the data with an area given in EPSG:3785 or EPSG:4326. In which projection you want to get the selected features, in native one of re-projected into EPSG:4326? Do you want to select or clip? Clip is splitting features which intersect the selection box, selecting means selecting the whole features without splitting them.

Comment: My I'm trying to select, but in a bounding box that I can specify. Is that possible with `ogr2ogr`? I thought it was the `-clipsrc`, but after hearing you explain that, I'm pretty sure that's not what I want.

Comment: Yes you can. But in the query in your question you are trying to select features which are in the database in EPSG:3785 projection with extents which you express in EPSG:4326. You should understand what it means and you should be able to answer the questions in my last comment before it makes sense to continue.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. So I need to convert the database to 4326 before moving forward, yes? [If you have some time to chat, I'd appreciate it](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38234/discussion-between-bdd-and-user30184).

Comment: No, you do not need to convert data. But if you want to select EPSG:3785 geometries with EPSG:4326 extents you must tell it to ogr2ogr with addition switch. All the switches are documented in http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html. Documentation is not very clear, I admit. Read carefully, make some tests, and come back to gis.stackexchange with a new focused question about what you did not understand despite the hard work that you did.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure, but when reading the ogr2ogr documentation, the -clipdst and -clipdstsql seems to relate to destination data object and therefore might not be relevant to this operation.

Is there a reason why you chose those variables?

I would suggest using the following syntax (untested):

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON ./test-buildings.geojson PG:"host=localhost dbname=gis 
user=*USERNAME* port=5432" -spat -84.419932 33.992761 -84.371342 34.018029 -clipsrc 
-sql 'SELECT way, "building" as type FROM planet_osm_polygon ORDER BY ST_YMin(ST_Envelope(way)) 
DESC' -progress
```

In this case I define the extent of the target area with the -spat variable and use the -clipsrc variable to clip the geometries to the -spat variable. I define the sql statement with the -sql variable

Comment: `-clipsrc` requires a reference, so I don't think `-spat` is required? I used `-clipdst` because it worked.